# Duplicate items being created during reimport in NSFileProviderEnumerator

Tags: ios, swift, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension

I am working on an NSFileProviderEnumerator in my iOS application to enumerate the contents of a directory. However, I'm experiencing an issue where duplicate items are being created during the reimport process.

Here is my enumeration code snippet:

```
items.append(FileProviderItem(
    identifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier(rawValue: item.mid),
    name: item.name,
    kind: item.kind.rawValue,
    parent: parent,
    size: size,
    modificationDateInMilliseconds: modificationDateInMilliseconds ?? nil))
```

The problem arises when I have a folder at the root level, let's say "Root". When I trigger reimport, it creates a duplicate folder named "Root2". And when I restart the app, "Root2" appears inside the "Root" folder. This is not the intended behavior - I would like the reimport to enumerate the existing items without creating duplicates.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I would appreciate any insights on how to correctly enumerate contents during reimport without creating duplicate items. Thanks in advance.

Comment: During reimport the system calls `createItem(basedOn:fields:contents:options:request:completionHandler:)` for each item it knows about with the `mayAlreadyExist` option set. If you are not handling this option correctly in your createItem implementation, then it may result in duplicated files.